# Presentamos Winter Bash 2015

Tags: discusión

Estamos terminando otro año y eso sólo puede significar una cosa. Ha llegado la hora del evento que os colma de alegría a todos (con una ligera ración de frustración para nuestros amigos del hemisferio sur<sup>1</sup>): **¡Winter Bash!**

[image: O... Summer Bash para muchos de vosotros]

Desde ahora y hasta el final del día 3 de enero de 2016, de nuevo podrás ganar y mostrar sombreros por hacer todo lo que ya llevas haciendo en los sitios de la red Stack Exchange. Al igual que en años anteriores, para este evento estamos desplegando una colección de sombreros completamente nuevos (por si te lo preguntas, esto es porque en el equipo de SE amamos nuestras comunidades y creemos que merecen lo mejor, no porque olvidamos dónde guardamos los sombreros cada año). Y esto significa que debemos estar tremendamente agradecidos a nuestro diseñador freelance, [Elias Stein](http://www.eliasstein.com), quien muy hábilmente se ha encargado de convertir vagos conceptos de sombreros locos en hermosuras digitales por tercer año consecutivo.

Los sombreros, para quienes no lo sepan, son algo así como las medallas, pero **mejores** porque los puedes "vestir" en tu avatar, mostrándolos donde quiera que tu avatar aparezca, ¡en toda la red! (y gracias al acto de amor de [Brian Nickel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/860000/brian-nickel), ¡este año esto incluye también la aplicación de iOS!). Los actos que otorgan sombreros son un poco diferentes de los que otorgan medallas; para saber qué tienes que hacer para obtener estos ornamentos, visita [el mini-sitio de Winter Bash](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com). Hay un total de 28 sombreros que puedes ganar en las próximas semanas… más otros de los que no te vamos a decir nada. ¿Cuántos sombreros secretos hay, te estarás preguntando? Eso lo tendrás que averiguar por ti mismo. No vamos a estropearte la sorpresa.

Una vez que hayas conseguido algunos sombreros, puedes visitar tu perfil en cualquiera de los sitios para elegir qué sombrero quieres llevar (o simplemente para admirar tu colección personal de sombreros). Haz clic en el gorro que adorna tu sección de medallas para que aparezca un cuadro de diálogo.

[image: El gorro en verano es una opción arriesgada]

(No, tú no puedes llevar el gorro. ¡Tus medallas podrían resfriarse!)

[image: No todos los sombreros tienen por qué ser iguales, ¿verdad?]

Al elegir un sombrero, podrás cambiar su tamaño y posición en la ventana de selección para que le quede bien a tu avatar. La imagen de ejemplo del año pasado fue tan perfecta que simplemente la hemos vuelto a usar:

[image: Shog9: Cazador de vampiros]][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lMdh.png)

Por último, no tienes que preocuparte de gestionar todo esto por ti mismo. Recibirás notificaciones sobre nuevos sombreros mediante un buzón especial sólo para Winter Bash en la barra superior: [image: Es bastante reputación, eh...].

Por supuesto, si piensas que todo esto es una tontería y no quieres participar, está bien, no vamos a juzgarte (mucho). Puedes desvincularte de este evento haciendo clic en el icono del copo de nieve en la barra superior—[image: ¿Nieve? ¿¿En pleno verano???]—y entonces en el enlace “odio los sombreros” que hay en la parte inferior izquierda del cuadro que aparecerá. (Nota: en Stack Overflow se aplica lo opuesto; los fans de los sombreros en SO tendrán que pasar por el mismo procedimiento pero haciendo clic en un enlace al final para **apuntarse**). Puedes cambiar de idea sobre tu participación en el evento durante toda la duración del mismo.

Simplemente recuerda que todos los sombreros desaparecerán tras tres semanas. Y ahora, ¡adelante! ¡Otras personas ya están trabajando para conseguir sus grados<sup>2</sup>!

1: Como en el pasado, la tradición derrotó a la precisión a la hora de decidir el nombre. Con suerte, parte de nuestra audiencia veraniega se calmará gracias al hecho de que el sitio de Winter Bash estará este año disponible en portugués, español, japonés y ruso, gracias a los esfuerzos de nuestros Community Managers internacionales.

2: La Universidad de Winter Bash no ha sido acreditada por ninguna organización reconocida por el Consejo para la Acreditación de Educación Superior del Departamento de Educación de los Estados Unidos. *Aún.*

Comment: +1 por la nota sobre el hemisferio sur :)

Comment: Hey... España no es para nada hemisferio sur (ni tampoco Portugal, Rusia y Japón, por cierto) :-P

Comment: @Konamiman uff, mis disculpas a los residentes y ciudadanos del gran país de España. No se implica ninguna falta de respeto con la omisión. :D

Comment: Al parecer no todos son sombreros, yo tengo una máscara no tan alegre.

Comment: Pensé que tendría los acumulados del año pasado también T_T

Comment: @CésarBustíos Lamentablemente, los sombreros no permanecen en las cuentas. Cada año empezamos de nuevo. :)

Comment: @JuanM que pena, deberían ser coleccionables ;)

Comment: @JuanM Bueno, de todas formas no estamos teniendo un invierno muy frio por aquí :-)

Comment: En ocasiones no es buena tanta nieve haha...

Comment: Excelente la adición de controles para tamaño y rotación de los sombreros, anteriormente había que cambiar la foto de perfil para que se ajustara a la posición de algunos sombreros, pero ya no más :)

Comment: Ah, ya desaparecieron, no queda algún tipo de historial para poder contemplarlos después? =(

Comment: _Podría_ ser buen momento para que este post deje de ser Featured :)

Comment: @mgarciaisaia tienes razón, ya no esta Featured :)

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque está obsoleta

Answer (score 0):

Ah, ya desaparecieron, no queda algún tipo de historial para poder contemplarlos despues? =(

Comment: Los sombreros se guardan hasta el siguiente WinterBash.  Desafortunadamente, no existen historiales.

Comment: ¿Qué quieres decir con que se guardan? ¿Podré ver mis sombreros que ya tenía en el siguiente Winter Bash?