# ¿Para qué sirven los sombreros? ¿Puedo ignorarlos totalmente?

Tags: soporte, winterbash-2017

He empezado a recibir notificaciones sobre algunos sombreros que he ¿*ganado*?.

En realidad, hace dos días vi el iconito de *nieve*  en la parte superior del panel, pero no le hice mucho caso.

¿Qué son los sombreros y qué utilidad tienen? ¿Es algo que suele aparecer para estas fechas en SO?

**¿Puedo ignorar el asunto de los sombreros, puesto que no le veo absolutamente ninguna utilidad?**

> P.D.: Como dato curioso, justamente cuando editaba esta pregunta,
>   tenía una notificación en el iconito de *nieve*, hice click en el
>   icono y debajo había algo que decía *Odio los sombreros*, con un
>   enlace. Cuando hice clic allí, ¡me dirigió a esta misma pregunta!.

Comment: https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Principalmente puedes verte [mas cool y con un look diferente](https://coresites-cdn.factorymedia.com/mpora_new/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Weird-Helmets.jpg)... haha

Comment: Aquí hay una publicación de JuanM donde indica todos los detalles del [primer Winter Bash](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256/presentamos-winter-bash-2015) en 2015. Una tradición de cada año en los sitios de la red StackExchange

Comment: Gracias por los comentarios. He editado la pregunta... me gustaría saber si puedo ignorar el asunto de los sombreros, puesto que no le veo ninguna utilidad.

Comment: Igual, los sombreros se van solitos el 3 de enero.. asi que tambien puedes no hacerles caso y desapareceran.. pero son COOOLLLL :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Es un "juego" en el que los usuarios tratan de obtener el mayor número de sombreros, o los sombreros mas raros, o algunos que son secretos. Pero un juego en definitiva. Es una tradición de SO desde hace varios años y se realiza todos los años durante estas fechas. Aqui tienes información sobre el [Winter Bash 2017](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/).

En cuanto a ignorarlo,es sencillo. Pincha en el icono del copo de nieve, y en la parte de abajo hay un enlace que dice "Odio los sombreros". Pulsa ahi para no participar del juego.

Comment: Gracias. Efectivamente, vi ese enlace e hice clic en él. El icono de *nieve*  sigue apareciendo, veremos si dejo de recibir notificaciones sobre los dichosos *sombreros*.

Comment: @A.Cedano efectivamente, el icono permanece aunque hayas desactivado tu participación. Hay formas de ocultarlo usando algun bloqueador, aunque no se si merece la pena. [Aqui tienes mas info](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/339932/579895)

Comment: El icono sigue ahí en caso de que los quieras volver a activar.

Comment: Hay una opción que dice odio los sombreros ahi podes desactivarlos